# Android: do startService and startActivity share an execution queue?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

When executing the following in sequence:

```
{
    Intent s = new Intent(...);
    context.startService(s);

    Intent a = new Intent(...);
    context.startActivity(a);
}
```

are both calls processed fully async? or do they share some kind of execution/ work-queue so that the above will still execute in a sequential fashion(meaning that the onStartCommand(..) will be fully executed before the onCreate(..) of the activity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls are fully asynchronous. The service and/or activity you are starting may exist in another OS process, so the calls could happen in parallel. Anyway, upon completion of the `startService()` call it is highly unlikely that the service's `onStartCommand()` has been completed, so you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: I would have said that it depends on the process that resolves the intent (in case it is implicit). Services and activities of the same app (and process) share the same (ui) thread, which means that the intents are queued and executed one at the time.

Comment: @fedepaol Good point. However, I wouldn't write code that depended on that, even if you know that the activity and service are running in the same process, it is likely to bite you later.

Comment: Me neither :-) I was just trying to remember how the things worked when I read your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was indeed talking about services and activities in the same process container.